# Node js - Express js code is executing after redirect

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express web app.  And within the app, I have a route that makes several calls to the database.  During each call, if it fails, then I am redirecting the browser to a page /temporarily-unavailable (basically a generic error page that doesn't freak the user out, just says try back later).

PORTION OF PSEUDO-CODE

```
app.get('/sign-in/twitter', function(req, res, next){
    request({
        'method' : 'GET',
        // BLAH BLAH BLAH CALL TO DATABASE
        // DATABASE CALLBACK
        function (error, response, body){
            if (response.statusCode === 200) {
                // DO GOOD STUFF
            }
            else if (response.statusCode === 404) {
                // DO COOL STUFF
            }
            else {
                temporarilyUnavailable(req, res, next);
            }
            // DO MORE STUFF AND SEND A RESPONSE
        }
    }
}
```

PORTION OF PSEUDO-CODE FOR TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE FUNCTION

```
res.set({
    'Cache-Control' : 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate,
    'Content-Type' : 'text/plain;charset=utf-8',
}

res.redirect(302, 'https://' + req.host + '/' + url);
```

Shoudn't the res.redirect in the TEMPORARILY UNAVAILABLE FUNCTION prevent any code further down from being executed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

You're simply calling a function on the response.  Code below it can execute.  There is nothing magical about `res.redirect()`.

A common practice to avoid this is to simply return when you redirect or otherwise call a callback where you want to exit the current function:

```
return res.redirect(302, 'https://' + req.host + '/' + url);
```

Comment: What about something like res.end() ?  I guess I am looking for something similar to next() that basically halts all further action with the request.

Comment: @JustinCloud `next()` doesn't halt anything.  Code can run after it as well.

Comment: Yes, but doesn't next() exit the current route and move on to the next routes?

Comment: @JustinCloud `next()` is just Another Function Call. Any code following it will be executed as well.

Comment: @JustinCloud Calling the `next()` function doesn't exit anything, just as calling any other callback or function wouldn't.  It's also good practice to return after (or with) `next()` as well.  `return next()`

Comment: @JustinCloud The benefit is that you exit out of the current function, like you are expecting.